# How write begin_export html blocks in an inline fashion?

Tags: org-babel, html

A code which takes up several lines of screen realestate can be written as

```
Inline code src_sh[:exports code]{echo -e "test"} foo
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16193498

Is is possible to write "inline", this kind of blocks:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16193498

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
the quick <b>brown</b> fox
#+END_EXPORT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html), alongside the explanation of `#+BEGIN_EXPORT html`

```
@@html:the quick <b>brown</b> fox@@
```